# Android Tap Highlight Jelly Bean

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

Im having a problem with my app on android 4.1.1. i have created a app with html/javascript with phonegap. My problem is that when links get clicked they show the orange highlight. i was able to fix this with **-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)**  or **-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)** but now i installed Jelly Bean and it is not working anymore.

Comment: Erind, could you clarify on which platform it was working and on which it's now not working? Your only Android reference is 4.1/JellyBean. As to the problem, let me try a stab in the dark: some people report seeing double events with Phonegap on Android 4.1. See: http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/597/duplicated-tap-event-on-android-4-1-jelly-bean-with-enyo-1-0 So perhaps your links are being selected then quickly de-selected as in that post. Dunno.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i was able to fix this with the -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0). As i was running on ice cream sandwich i had no problems with the-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) but i guess i had something written wrong that didnt work on jellybean.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  I got rid of the orange highlight on Jelly Bean by using this:

```
* {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in Jelly Bean. I tried using $(".elems").on("touchend", function(){ return false; }); and that seemed to work on 4.1.1, but does not work on 4.3...